# Which solution can be managed to be a closed group for microblogging and a team?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, joomla, buddypress, diaspora

I want to find a solution to make webpage for closed group (private) in which is possible for accounts with writting ability to post twitter like messeges when new info needed to be posted and that it can have many teams like Project Team A & B.

Each user could be in many teams. All team writings can be viewable in one page but on other page only those writings that comes from only each users teams which can be 2 or 3.

Example for twitter is the wordpress.com theme http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2009/03/11/p2-the-new-prologue/.

But it lacks need of being able to make Teams. It has tags but every time tag needs to be written so if it would be possible to auto make if I'm from Team A then tag all my team tags on each my post automatically.

Either existing service for that just register (wordpress, identi.ca) or service like kodingen.com where i can deploy Joomla or other CMS.

A CMS like joomla I hope some has some solution with plugins or wordpress cms that has that theme I mentioned. Diaspora, maybe but haven't tried it. Buddypress.com just somehow came on google when randomly searched.

Twitter can be private but only for whole account so I need new account that is OK, but it doesn't have auto tags if I'm from Team A.

Facebook can't have privacy. All users will be anonymous so new profile making in FB could be good and making groups and all users invite only each other, but they need to be anonymous, which is opposite of facebook. Maybe even workflow will be interupted if some user gets banned becuase it's a Narwhal or Dragon.

Optionally, pages can also be made and even better if collaborative, like Google Wave or Docs can be made and added countdown timer added. Countdown is more needed comparing to page writing like Docs or Wave that can be just any small Wiki plugin.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing a private forum.

Answer (score 1):

You want to allow users to edit, but control who can view and edit what content according to what user-group ( a.k.a. 'team') they belong to, right?

Comment: Yes. Main thing that secure and private.